# symbolic link to bit bucket

Tags: mysql, unix

How do I throw the contents of binary log to bit bucket? I tried to create a soft link but it did not work. 
I do not want to save mysql general log but I want to watch it using tail -f command.

ln -s /dev/null /var/log/mysql/mysql-gen.log

ln: creating symbolic link /var/log/mysql/mysql-gen.log to /dev/null: File exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ln -fs /dev/null /var/log/mysql/mysql-gen.log
```

See [`man 1 ln`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) or [info coreutils 'ln invocation'](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ln-invocation.html).

> ‘`-f`’
>   ‘`--force`’
>       Remove existing destination files.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the log file (/var/log/mysql/mysql-gen.log) first before creating it as a symbolic link.

```
/tmp/test>touch somefile
/tmp/test>ln -s /dev/null somefile
ln: creating symbolic link `somefile': File exists
/tmp/test>rm somefile
/tmp/test>ln -s /dev/null somefile
/tmp/test>ls -l somefile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 9 Oct 16 17:04 somefile -> /dev/null
/tmp/test>
```